# Error in dynamic SQL query. Missing expression with correct syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, dynamic-sql, ora-00936

I have a problem working with a stored procedure on work.

It's a stored procedure which is used by several bigger procedures. The procedure which does the work is called `C`, and the ones who call it are `A` and `B`.

The problem I have is that when I run `A`, everything goes smoothly, but when I run `B`, I get a `missing expression error`, which I don't get when I call `A`, even tough `B` and `A` have the same flow of procedure calls (so, it's kind of a really weird error).

The `C` procedure has the same code:

```
procedure C ( LO in varchar2,
              EN in varchar2,
              CA in array1d,
              IA in number,
              AR in array2d )
is
  CQ varchar2(5);
  ET varchar2(2000);
  OL varchar2(100);
  NE varchar2(100);
  TE varchar2(100);
  XU varchar2(100);
begin
  LO := '05';
  TE := 'VAR';
  CQ := '''';
  OL := CQ || LO || CQ;
  TE := CQ || TE || CQ;
  NE := CQ || EN || CQ;

  ET := 'PAR1 = ' || CA(1) || ',' ||
        'PAR2 = ' || CA(2) || ',' ||
        'PAR3 = ' || CA(3) || ',' ||
        'PAR4 = ' || CA(4) || ',' ||
        'PAR5 = ' || CA(5) || ',' ||
        'PAR6 = ' || CA(6) || ',' ||
        'PAR7 = ' || CA(7) || ',' ||
        'PAR8 = ' || CA(8) || ',' ||
        'PAR9 = ' || CA(9);

  execute immediate 'update table_st set ' || ET || '
                      where field1 = ' || OL || '
                        AND field2 = ' || NE || '
                        AND field3 = ' || TE;
end;
```

The error I get is `missing expression`, and it seems to appear on the first line of the `execute immediate`. After some analysis, I realized the data from the 2d ARRAY is initialized with some empty strings `''`.

I am wondering if you could help me to see this error from a new perspective, because as I see it, there seems to be no syntax error to justify the `missing expression error` I get, but I know I may be wrong.
If further details are needed, let me know.

Comment: just watching the code sintaxis highlight look like some string arent ended properly

Comment: Double check the line `CQ  := q'[']';`

Comment: and the last line `AND field3 = ' || TE;` also need one ending `'`

Comment: nevermind, looks that way because the `q'[']'` above

Comment: @Samcd I already checked the line, and it seems to be OK. There are another stored procedures which use the same value, so I think that's not the issue.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yeah. It seems weird on my text editor too, but when I look at the IDE (which I connect using SSH), the string is quoted correctly. I thnik it's because the Oracle is customized for Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, I'd say the variables LO, CQ haven't been declared, and EN and CA haven't been declared or initialized.

Also, you declared NE as a `verchar2` when I think you meant `varchar2`.

I also agree with Juan's observation that you may want to double check this line:

```
CQ  := q'[']';
```

Did you mean:

```
CQ  := q'['']';
```

Honestly not sure, but worth a look.

Oracle should tell you if the procedure compiles, and I think these errors alone will prevent it from doing that.  If you don't ever declare the contents of EN and CA, it might still compile but fail when it runs.

Comment: Re-reading your question, maybe these were parameters to the procedure?  Can you post the header also?  Maybe your only error is the verchar2.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, it had some typos. Those ara parameters, initialized outside. As I said, the trouble seems to be in the execute immediate line. I wonder if it's related to the values of the matrix being '' (empty strings).
By the way, the line 
`CQ := q'[']'; ` 
it's fine because it appears in another stored procedures which work OK.

Comment: If you don't have a debugger, I'd recommend you create a dummy table `create table foo (bar as varchar2(1000)` and change that last line from `execute immediate` to `insert into foo values (  your SQL here )`.  This way you can visualize what the SQL is that it's trying to execute or even know if it makes it that far.

Comment: I have no debugger nor auxiliary tools. I'll try the dummy table insertion.

Comment: Ok. The values that is inserting are '1' character followed by 8 times '' (empty string).